# Why can't I index this php array by its key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array called $slot. I receive this as a $POST param upon a form submission.

When I do `print_r($slot)`, the php script shows the contents of this array:

```
Array ( ['start_time'] => 12:00 PM ['end_time'] => 1:00 PM )
```

I want to be able to grab the times (12:00 PM & 1:00 PM) by simply indexing this array. However when I try to do:

```
echo $slot['start_time']
```

Nothing gets displayed! I am perplexed why I can't simply retrieve the values by indexing the array. I am still getting used to PHP and would appreciate any insights you guys might have.

Thank you.

**Full code**

```
foreach ($_POST['slots'] as $slot) {
        print_r($slot);
        echo $slot["start_time"];

}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( ['start_time'] => 12:00 PM ['end_time'] => 1:00 PM )
```

so it executes the print_r statement as expected but not echoing the start_time

Comment: Are you sure that is the output? Show us your code.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/7y8vHj

Comment: We're going to need something reproducible to be able to help you.

Comment: Are you missing semi-colons in your code like you are in your post?

Comment: @McRed possible formatting error?

Comment: I added more descriptive output

Comment: Is `$_POST['slots']` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have single quotes in your array keys so you have `'start_time'` not `start_time`. Remove the quotes from the keys or access it with quotes:

```
echo $slot["'start_time'"];
```

Comment: Yes, this works completely! Thank you. I had messed up naming the param in my form and added the single quotes.